# Blender Save Video into Blend

Tags: game-engine, video

I am using this script for playing videos on planes, cubes etc. It is working fine for me, but when I send my runtime to my friends (videos included in the folder), the videos wont show up (only missing texture magenta color).

So I hope somebody can help me that I can play videos in the .exe when my friends start it.

SCRIPT:

```
#import GameLogic
import GameLogic

# get current scene
scene = GameLogic.getCurrentScene()

# get the current controller
controller = GameLogic.getCurrentController()

# get object script is attached to
obj = controller.owner

# check to see video has been added
if "Video" in obj:

    # get video 
    video = obj["Video"]

    # update the video 
    video.refresh(True)

# if video hasn't been added 
else:

    # import VideoTexture module
    import VideoTexture

    # get matID for the movie screen    
    matID = VideoTexture.materialID(obj, "MA" + obj['material'])

    # get the texture
    video = VideoTexture.Texture(obj, matID)

    movieName = obj['movie']

    # get movie path
    movie = GameLogic.expandPath('//' + movieName)

    # get movie
    video.source = VideoTexture.VideoFFmpeg(movie)

    # set scaling
    video.source.scale = True   

    # save mirror as an object variable
    obj["Video"] = video

    # check for optional loop property
    if "loop" in obj:

        # loop it forever
        if obj['loop'] == True:
            video.source.repeat = -1

        # no looping
        else:
            video.source.repeat = 0

    # start the video
    video.source.play()
```